How to convert QuantumCircuit to OpenQasm 2.0 in qiskit 1.0+
I need to convert a QuantumCircuit to a string of the equivalent OpenQasm 2.0 circuit in qiskit.
It seems like the method .qasm() disappeared from the QuantumCircuit class in qiskit 1.0
And I wasn't able to find an alternative.
I need the qiskit 1.0 version of this:
c  = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(1)
c.h(0)

c.qasm()


You can take a look at this link. Here the qiskit documentation describes how to import and export to OpenQASM 2.0

This changed in Qiskit 1.0.  You can still export to QASM code, but there is no more QuantumCircuit.qasm() method.
https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/qiskit-1.0-features#quantumcircuitqasm
The new method is
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
 
from qiskit.qasm2 import dumps
qasm_str = dumps(qc)

